# Get subset of path with specified folder

Tags: python, path, os.path

Suppose i have a path:

```
'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4'
```

Question is How Can i get subset of this path up to specified folder plus one directory down from specified folder. 
Of course this should be generic, so folder names could be different.

For example with path from above, I specify such directory:

```
'Folder2'
```

And i want to get this path as a result:

```
'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) library has lots of features to manage paths. then a recursive method could allow to find the correct folder. try something like this:

```
import os

def find_folder( path, folder_name):
    head, tail = os.path.split(path)
    if folder_name == os.path.split(head)[1]:
        return path
    else:
        return find_folder(head, folder_name)

path = 'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4'
print find_folder(path, 'Folder2')
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you can try to split the path for example

```
  import os

  a=r"'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4'"
  a.split(os.pathsep)
```

result is :

```
  ['C:', 'Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Folder4']
```

remove the one you want 
and concatenate after that the path .

Thanks and good luck !